# How can I load and store data for a large map in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, data-structure

I'm working on a tower defense game. I have this structure: 
`int array (public int[,,,] gridArray = new int[2000, 2000, 9, 9];)`

that I'm using as a map-bible; by map-bible I mean that the array holds all the cell data that the game uses to build its map form.

What I am specifically asking for is a way to store that data in any file format without needing to massively rework my game.

The first two dimensions of the array store x and y, while the last two dimensions hold cell-specific data. In most cases, this cell-specific data stores building health or ammo. But the vast majority of the 81 cells are empty to accommodate more things down the line. It should be noted that all this data is simply integers that are passed on to game objects, for example: 
`newbuilding.health = gridArray [x,y,0,1];`

It should be noted I am a novice level programmer and in way over my head, so detail would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work as you expected?

Comment: and thats a kinda big file if you fully populate it. 4 byte per int *2000 * 2000 * 9 * 9 is 1296 Megabyte

Comment: Over the past week, I have tried JSON. But it, by default, will not serialize multidimensional arrays. Dipped my toes into XML, but as I said, I'm a novice, so that was a hard pass. and finally decided against binary for obvious reasons. And ya its a good amount of data.

Comment: What does this data represent, and where does it come from or get generated/input? Those kinds of details can help us find approaches suited to your needs.

Comment: Tell us the "obvious reasons" you decided against binary please? Because a binary format will let you just read or write the entire thing in a single operation, bottlenecked only by disk speed. Text formats will always require slower parsing and data conversion, so you better have a very compelling reason for not preferring binary.

Comment: @DMGregory the data more or less represents a settlement with the 
The first two dimensions storeing x and y. and the last two dimensions storing "Cell" specific data, building health, resources, etc..

Comment: And you have 81 different pieces of cell-specific data in every cell?

Comment: @Maximus Minimus, I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido&feature=emb_logo
and the resulting file was just over 1.2 gigabytes of data, taking over half an hour to do so; sorry for the assumption.

Comment: not to mention the 4.000.000 populated cells and yes, it is 1.2gb big since each int is 4 byte and do the math for your array: 4 byte per int *2000 * 2000 * 9 * 9 is 1296 Megabyte

Comment: @DMGregory, yes, each cell has a good amount of storage, but most of it is empty, so optimization wish I could minimize it. But with the game only taking 10 seconds to boot up, it seems inconsequential.

Comment: It sounds like you have a more fundamental problem of designing a sparse data structure that serves your needs without needing a 1.2 gigabyte storage/memory footprint. Want to edit your question to ask that instead?

Comment: Is your data per cell unique or more like a general description of the object in the cell? Do you need to load your level all at once or can you load part of it? Is this for pc or mobile?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm going to be honest, I have no idea what most of that means. Could you be more direct in what I should be asking?

Comment: @ Zibelas for your first question I don't really know what your asking, but yes I need to load your level all at once (and already do so). and this game is for PC.

Comment: Try asking "How can I load and store data for a large map" and in the body of the question, give us a breakdown of what data you need to store and its purpose. I'm betting there are some significant opportunities to find a more efficient solution than 1.2 gigs of integers, while still supporting everything your game mechanics require.

Comment: @DMGregory I should make it clear that that 1.2 gigs of integers was only after converting the array into binary.

Comment: Hint: it's binary in memory too.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: The reason I asked you to edit your question to include a more detailed breakdown of your specific data needs was because I wanted more insight than what you'd already told us in the comments. Just repeating yourself does not move us forward. We need to know what this per-cell data is. What's the significance of the 9x9 dimensions? You mentioned most of it is empty — what logic determines what parts are empty or not? The better we can understand the *function* of your game and how this data serves your gameplay mechanics, the better we can tailor answers to those needs.

Comment: @DMGregory The per-cell data varies from building type to building type, and its structure is rather chaotic at this point, but you can kind of just think of the 9*9 as a file for whatever I feel like storing.

Comment: Which is the wrong approch. You might want to store what type of building there is. And its current health. But everything else of the building stats can be saved once (not in the cell) and then just looked up to check what they are. So you only need to store data that can change, not all of them. And what is happening offscreen in your game, for what reason does your game need to be fully loaded at once?

Comment: Have you considered using a chunk system, like Minecraft?  Additionally, for objects in the "cells", consider using an object pool which might, depending on how the game works, decrease memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

> What I am specifically asking for is a way to store that data in any file format without needing to massively rework my game.

> It should be noted I am a novice level programmer and in way over my head, so detail would be appreciated.

No offense, but the clumsy way you're storing your data is just making things worse for you. You should seriously consider changing it, even if that means you need to rework some of your game. If you start from a bad foundation and just keep building on that bad foundation, you're just going to end up with code that is more and more of a mess until it gets to the point that it's impossible to make any progress. This often means giving up on the project and sometimes giving up on game development altogether.

In the engine, your data should probably be stored more along the lines of something like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct Cell {
    [SerializeField] private int x;
    [SerializeField] private int y;
    [SerializeField] private BuildingInfo buildingInfo;
    [SerializeField] private int ammo;

    public int X{ get => x; set => x = value; }
    public int Y{ get => y; set => y = value; }
    public Vector2Int Position => new Vector2Int(x, y);
    public BuildingInfo BuildingInfo { get => buildingInfo; set => buildingInfo = value; }
    public int Ammo { get => ammo; set => ammo = value; }
    //etc
}

//if most cells will have data, we can consider a 2D table:
private Cell[,] cells = new Cell[2000, 2000];
//to retrieve a cell
var cell = cells[x,y];

//or if most cells will not have data, we should not waste an enormous amount of
//space populating a 2D table with empty cells
private Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> cells = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell>(100);
//to add a cell:
var cell = new Cell();
cell.X = x;
cell.Y = y;
//etc
cells.Add(cell.Position, cell);

//to retrieve a cell
if (cells.TryGetValue(new Vector2Int(x, y), out var cell) {
    //do something with the cell here
}
//to loop through all cells
foreach (var cell in cells.Values) {
    //do something with the cell here
}
```

Because the struct in my example is serializable, you can put the structs into a ScriptableObject:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Saved Map")]
public class SavedMap : ScriptableObject {
    [SerializeField] private List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>(100);

    public List<Cell> Cells { get => cells; set => cells = value; }

    public void SaveFromDictionary(Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> dict) {
        cells.Clear();
        foreach (var cell in dict.Values) {
            cells.Add(cell);
        }
        //special code that only runs in the Editor to make sure the Editor recognizes that the data changed and needs to be saved to disk
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
#endif
    }

    //this is very expensive, only call it once when you start the game and save the result to a variable
    public Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> ToDictionary() {
        Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> dict = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell>(cells.Count);
        foreach (var cell in cells) {
            dict[cell.Position] = cell;
        }
        return dict;
    }
}

public class MapLoader : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private SavedMap map;
    private Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> cells;

    private void Awake() {
        Assert.IsNotNull(map);
        cells = map.ToDictionary();
    }

    public Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> Cells => cells;
}
```

A ScriptableObject class defines a type of asset file that you can create, edit, and save in the Unity Editor. You can edit a ScriptableObject asset in the Inspector in the same way you edit any GameObject. In this case manually editing the cells in the Inspector would be a nightmare, so you'd probably want to have a script pass the data into the ScriptableObject to save.

If you don't know how to use Dictionaries or ScriptableObjects or anything else I've mentioned, please do a web search and read the official documentation. This is the best way to learn!

You might also want to eventually make a custom `Editor` or `EditorWindow` script for easily editing a SavedMap in the Unity Editor.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and oh, dont worry I have no illusions about how much better I could have done things form the beginning.